# How do i efficiently feed a 2d python list to a c++ extension module

Tags: python, c++, module

I am writing a python 3.5 module in c++ and I want to feed a 2d list from python to c++ - preferably to a std::vector. The working code is below, however I was hoping that I could avoid copying the data and instead point a 2d array to the address &input_value. Is there a better way to do this?

```
PyObject* CheckTerminal(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  PyObject *input_value;
  std::vector<std::vector<bool>> cArray;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &input_value))
  {
    std::cout << "\nerror\n";
    goto error;
  }

  int count = (int)PyList_Size(input_value);
  PyObject *ptemp,*vals;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    cArray.push_back(std::vector<bool>());
    ptemp = PyList_GetItem(input_value, i);
    int count2 = (int)PyList_Size(ptemp);
    for (int j = 0; j < count2; ++j)
    {

        vals = PyList_GetItem(ptemp, j);
        int v = PyLong_AsLong(vals);

        if (v == 1)
        {
            cArray[i].push_back(true);
        }
        else if (v == 0)
        {
            cArray[i].push_back(false);
        }

    }

  }

  return PyBool_FromLong(g.CheckTerminal(&cArray));

error:
  return 0;
}
```

After importing this module I call it from python with;

```
p=[[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
print(nInARow.CheckTerminal(p))
```

Comment: The problem is that Python lists are arrays of pointers, not arrays of values, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using PyObject's instead of converting to C++ array. Accessing the data inside the pyobject is done by PyList_GetItem or PyList_GetSlice

```
// Checks if given boardState is terminal. 
PyObject* NInARowGame::CheckTerminal(PyObject* input_value)
{

    //this is just  check, should be the same number of planes.
    PyObject *p1 = PyList_GetItem(input_value, 0);
    PyObject *p2 = PyList_GetItem(input_value, 1);
    Py_INCREF(p1);
    Py_INCREF(p2);

    int count = (int)PyList_Size(input_value);

    auto nK = this->winsK.size();

    for (int i = 0; i<nK; ++i)
    {//for each winning kernel do the following
     //int ksizeY = k[0].size();

        if (compareK(p1, &this->winsK[i]))
        {
            winner = 1;
            return Py_True;

        }
        if (compareK(p2, &this->winsK[i]))
        {
            winner = 2;
            return Py_True;
        }


    }
    PyObject *m = this->GetMoves(); 
    int counter = (int)PyList_Size(m);

    if (counter==0) 
    {
        winner = 3;
        return Py_True;

    }
    Py_DECREF(p1);
    Py_DECREF(p2);
    return Py_False;
}
```

Comment: For completeness there is also a defined script available which is close: #define PyList_GET_ITEM(op, i) (((PyListObject *)(op))->ob_item[i])